# Wrong coordinates in a Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, embedded-linux, buildroot

I created a Qt Application with Qt Creator 3.3.1, using Qt embedded 4.8.6 for a Cortex A5. 
It runs on a board with Linux embedded and a touchscreen.
The filesystem was created with Buildroot 2015.08.
I'm using a resistive touchscreen calibrated with ts_calibrate. 
The Qt Application works, but I often get the wrong coordinates. For example, when I push on a button, sometimes the program takes the coordinates related to another point of the touchscreen, giving the idea that the button pushed doesn't work properly.

My Qt enviroment variable are:

```
  export TSLIB_CALIBFILE='/etc/pointercal'
  export TSLIB_CONFFILE='/etc/ts.conf'
  export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR='/usr/lib/ts'
  export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=`cat /etc/ts.dev 2>/dev/null`
  export QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=800:mmHeight=480
  export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=Tslib:/dev/input/event0
```

If I try to use another Qt Application (for example the Qt demos created with Buildroot) I get the same problem.
Is it a bug of Qt 4.8.6 or something?
Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Try using the utilities provided with tslib: `ts_test`, `ts_print` and `ts_print_raw`. If they have the same problem, it's not related with Qt.

Comment: I agree with Luca that this is most likely an issue with the touch screen itself - either in the driver, or (more likely) bad decoupling at the edges of the screen. The whole input stack (Linux driver, tslib, Qt) does nothing more than a linear transformation of the coordinates given by the touch screen controller. IOW, if you touch the same screen area two times and it gives two different coordinates, it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like playing with your activated filters or their parameters in `ts.conf` might help.

Since you asked your question, there is tslib 1.2 and (if you need multitouch) tslib 1.3-rc3, both with new and improved filters, see [tslib's project page](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14658483)

Comment: @Odedra this seems like more then a link only answer.